# How to pass input request to foreach loop in controller to store data

Tags: laravel, foreach, controller, request

I'm building a site with localizations using laravel. Trying to store names and texts in 3 languages using a form. I have a model for each article and another for article translations.
Using inputs for names and texts with input names like name_en, text_en, name_de, text_de etc...
But i can't figure out how to pass input values to a foreach loop in the store method in my controller.

I tried to pass (Request $request) object into foreach loop but it returns an error. Code is below:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $test = new Test;
    $test->isActive = true;
    $test->save();

    //TRANSLATED INPUTS = name_tr,text_tr,name_en,text_en,name_de,text_de

    foreach (['tr', 'en', 'de'] as $locale => $request)//OBVIOUSLY WRONG 
    {
        $test->translateOrNew($locale)->name = $request->input('name_'.$locale);
        $test->translateOrNew($locale)->text = $request->input('body_'.$locale);
    }

    $test->save();
    dd($test);
    //echo 'Created new article with some translations!';
}
```

Trying to get translated inputs itno database.

Comment: The `foreach` already has access to `$request` from the dependency injection, you don't need to include it as a value in your `foreach` block at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this the way you have it set up.  You could use a series of if `str contains`, then `str replace` on `name`, and `text`, until you get the right language.  But that's potentially a lot of work and likely pretty confusing if you have many names and texts coming from your form (which I assume you do from the need for a `foreach` on the incoming data).

I suggest you re-work your form slightly to return a bit more information.  Consider the following as possible elements to return from the form:

1. name[]
2. text[]
3. language[]

Then, in your store method you can run through each of these in a number of ways, but to explain, I'll use the clearest (though not the most efficient):

**Set an index:**

```
$i = 0;
```

**Run through all of the form's returns**, and get the corresponding text and language that comes with the name (through the same index):

```
foreach($request->get('name') as $name){
     $lang = $request['language'][$i];
     $test->translateOrNew($lang)->name = $name;
     $test->translateOrNew($lang)->text = $request['text'][$i];
     $i ++;
}
```

This is almost pseudo code, and you will have to re-factor to make it work for you, but it should give you one idea on how you might do this.  You will need to validate that the user provides each set (name, text, language) as complete, or the index will fail.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I followed a different approach and instead of using a loop i kinda used a 'hardcoded' multi-dimensional array for each language and stored them in a variable then saved.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it solved.  Yes, there are several ways to make this work :)